# Future pipeTo failure is wrapped inside akka.actor.status.Failure?

Tags: akka

When using the pipe pattern in Akka the future failed result is wrapped inside a akka.actor.status.Failure, however the future success result is NOT wrapped in the corresponding akka.actor.status.Success.

I was wondering what is the reasoning behind this decision? Why just the failure and not the success?

It seems more logical to not wrap anything at all.

Here is the link to the implementation:
https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.4-M2/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/pattern/PipeToSupport.scala

Answer (score 8):

Let's say you have an actor `A` that sends a message to actor `B` and `A` expects some sort of response message from `B`.  Inside of `B`, in order for it to do it's work, it needs a `Future` for some reason.  After that `Future` completes, it wants to send the result back to `A`.  The person who coded `B` wants to be careful to not close over the `sender()` when responding back to `A`, so they use the `pipeTo` pattern like so:

```
fut pipeTo sender()
```

Now back in `A`, you are expecting a response of a certain type, and you should not have to deal with the internal intricacies of actor `B` and the fact that it needed a `Future` in order to do it's work.  In other words, you don't want the response to come back to you wrapped in a `scala.util.Try` (`Success` or `Failure`).  If you expect a `String`, then if all goes well, that's exactly what you want back from `B`.  But in the case that everything does not go well in `B`, `A` needs to know this and the way that the Akka team chose to do so was to wrap it in `Status.Failure`.  This to me seems better than sending the raw `Exception` as is.

Now, us, we use a standard communication model between actors where we have something similar to this simple model (simplified for brevity):

```
sealed trait ServiceResult[+A]
case object EmptyResult extends ServiceResult[Nothing]
case class FullResult[+A](value:A) extends ServiceResult[A]
case class Failure(error:ErrorMessage, ex:Option[Throwable]) extends ServiceResult[Nothing]
```

All services always respond with some form of `ServiceResult`.  So if we are piping back to a `sender()` from a `Future` we do something like this:

```
fut.recover{case ex => Failure(someErrorMessage, Some(ex)} pipeTo sender()
```

That way we don't have to really deal with `Status.Failure` anywhere.

Comment: This is a great explanation to my intuition that `Status.Failure` is unnecessary. If you want to communicate to actor `A` that the operation he requested failed, you are going to encode that in a domain specific way. In other words, you will want to transform `Status.Failure` into some domain object. You skipped handling the Failure because your future never truly fails and so the success case in the `PipeableFuture` is always invoked.

Comment: As you said in your last statement, you avoided having to deal with `Status.Failure`, which somehow hints that it should not exist.

Comment: Akka needs it internally.  When you use `ask`, a short lived actor is used to broker the request/response semantic.  I imagine `Status.Failure` was used to tell that short lived actor to fail the upstream `Future` that it represents when a failure occurs.  I think that's why it exists.  It just so happens that it spills out though when you use `pipe` and you end up encountering it.  Also, if you know you are being invoked via ask. responding with `Status.Failure` is a quick way to fail the upstream `Future` without having to `flatMap` on the Future to inspect the result and maybe fail

Comment: Sending a message to an actor is much like creating a `Future` - these are both asynchronous actions. If Scala developers have chosen to use the format of success-failure for their asynchronous construct, why should Akka be different? That only creates confusion. Moreover, you say that you basically created your own custom `scala.util.Try`, which (may) indicate the common intuition of developers around this topic. I would've expected `pipeTo` to return as a `Try`, perhaps with the option to specify a custom return type (similar to `Try`) with something like `pipeTo actorX as MyCustomTry`.

Answer (score 1):

`future onComplete` will resolve to either `scala.util.Success(futureResult)` or `scala.util.Failure(someThrowable)`.

If the future succeeds, it is convenient to get back the `futureResult` directly.

If the future failed, you probably don't want to receive back an unwrapped throwable. It's nicer to get it back wrapped in `akka.actor.status.Failure`.

Comment: But doesn't scala.util.Failure already serve that purpose? And what is the problem of handling the scala.util.{Success, Failure} in the Actor?

Comment: But you don't get back akka.actor.status.Failure(scala.util.Failure(throwable)), you get back just akka.actor.status.Failure(throwable). It's not double-wrapped. And I think it makes more sense to get back the actor status failure than a future failure at that point.

Comment: I should've been more explicit. Why does the implementation wraps the failure inside a akka.actor.status.Failure and not inside a scala.util.Failure? A actor status failure is a failure. I don't see the need to reinvent the wheel (the failure) here.

Comment: The documentation on actor.status.Failure is: "This class/message type is preferably used to indicate failure of some operation performed. As an example, it is used to signal failure with AskSupport is used (ask/?)." When dealing with futures you get back a future failure, when performing operations on an actor, you get back an actor status failure. Makes sense to me.